# How to add a static element to the end of an xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

i have a xml

```
<reference ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>>
<doctype>  
<name>testing</name>
</doctype> 
<doctype>  
<name>testing2</name>
</doctype>
</reference>
```

I want to add/append a static tag below at the end of the xml. I hvae tried to find similar queries but unable to add them only one time at end.

Sample tag to mentioned below needs to be added at end (only once), just  before the reference tag closes.
Can you please help in guiding.

```
<doctype>  
<name>static_value_1</name>
</doctype>
<doctype>  
<name>static_value_2</name>
</doctype>
```

One method which i found one other links is mentioned below. But this will add at the end of each doctype everytime.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/doctype">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <doctype>  
        <name>static_value_1</name>
        </doctype>
       <doctype>  
       <name>static_value_2</name>
       </doctype>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This makes very little sense. The input you show is not XML. And your XSLT cannot possibly produce the result you claim it does: if it produces **any** result, then `doctype` is the root element. And if  `doctype` is the root element, then there is only one  `doctype`.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Is there a way to add any static elements at the end of the xml file (last line but one) using xslt or to check last but one line and add the static elements using xslt.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<xsl:template match="/doctype">
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
```

See transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYjq

Comment: Thanks Rupesh, Is there  a way to add at the end of the xml file (last line but one), seems reference match is matching incorrectly or is there a way to check last but one line and add the static elements using xslt.

Comment: @abhayn can you show me your desired output so that any body can understand the issue

Comment: Hi Rakesh,
Please find the desired output required.
I need to add static_value_1 and static_value_1 tags at the last but one line (tag), as the reference tag is not being found.
<reference ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>>
<doctype>  
<name>testing</name>
</doctype> 
<doctype>  
<name>testing2</name>
</doctype>
<doctype>  
<name>static_value_1</name>
</doctype>
<doctype>  
<name>static_value_2</name>
</doctype>
</reference>